# How to perform a git rollback via a Pull Request?

Tags: git, bitbucket, rollback, pull-request

We strictly use PRs to introduce changes to our `production` branch (as you would). My assumption was that a rollback would mean creating a `rollback` branch before merging the `feature` topic branch and if we require, we can rollback via the `rollback` PR. However this doesn't work as I thought.

**Create rollback branch:**

`git checkout 6af89ed -b rollback-prod`

**Merge Feature branch:**

```
# production branch
git merge new-feature
```

**Rollback:**

```
# production branch
git merge rollback-prod
Already up-to-date.
```

As you can see (correct me if I'm wrong) because the commit already exists in the `production` branch it relays `Already up-to-date`.

The issue I face is, this rollback needs to happen via our GUI git tool (bitbucket). So manual command fixes is not really an option.

Is there recommended way to rollback to a commit via a PR?

**EDIT 1:**

I'd like to make it clear that the `rollback` needs to be created in advance so that Ops do not have to touch the command-line in the event of a rollback..assuming this is possible, perhaps not.

Comment: New feature added on bitbucket. It now has revert button on a merged pull request. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/work-with-pull-requests-223220593.html#Workwithpullrequests-Revertapullrequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to effectively "rollback" a commit in Git.  One is to perform an interactive rebase in which you remove one or more commits, and the other is to do a `git revert`.  However, because you want to effect the rollback via a pull request, the only option is to do a `git revert`.  So you can try the following:

```
git checkout production
git checkout -b rollback-prod      # create rollback branch from production
git revert 6af89ed^..HEAD          # add revert commit to this branch
git push origin rollback-prod      # push this branch to Bitbucket
```

Now, you can create a pull request in Bitbucket for the `rollback-prod` branch.  Once it is completed, the `6af89ed` commit will be effectively reverted.

Comment: Please see my edit on why this is not the desired approach as per requirements.

Comment: You can't revert a commit in advance if that commit does not already exist.  AFAIK, the solution I gave is the only way to do this via a pull request, which uses merging to bring one branch into another.

Comment: From my understanding `git revert 6af89ed` only reverts the changes in the given commit. Is that correct? If the OP wants to revert all commits since that commit to HEAD, the command will need to be a little more complex.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It wasn't clear to me either what the OP wanted, be it a single commit reverted or something else.  I updated to give a range from `6af89ed` to the `HEAD`.

Comment: "You can't revert a commit in advance if that commit does not already exist. AFAIK, the solution I gave is the only way to do this via a pull request, which uses merging to bring one branch into another."

This is what I'm trying to clarify.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to clarify here.  You can't revert something which does not yet exist.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Well, the commit does exist as a historical commit on the `production` branch. If you are saying that a `git revert` is the only way to access that historical commit in a PR, then yes I see your point.

Comment: I will not comment further.  Either of the answers given should be sufficient for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the `rollback` branch at the current `master` (or wherever you need to start the rollback from) and use `git revert` on all of the commits that you want to undo. Now you have a branch which you can use with a pull request.

Comment: I thought about that but it also means the revert PR  can only be created after the merge. I'd like to create the `rollback` branch in advance to make it easier for Ops to rollback if necessary so that the command-line can be avoided.

Comment: @kaizenCoder Is this a one-time thing or is this something that you expect the Ops to need to do more often?

Comment: "it means the revert PR can only be created after the merge" Why?

Comment: You can't revert something which doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Well, it is a fallback activity in the even the code doesn't work as expected, so yes regular.. With regard to 'Why?', the revert is performed after the merge has occurred. I do understand that it is the point of a `revert` but my requirements state that the rollback branch be created prior, pointing at an existing commit/head on the `production` branch before the merge.

Comment: @kaizenCoder It sounds to me that you might have problems with your process that are independent of the technical tools you are using. IMO, there should be little reason to revert/rollback a commit which has made it into production. If this is a common occurrence, I suggest that you revisit your code review process to help reduce the need for such rollbacks.

Comment: I completely understand but perhaps I wasn't very clear. We don't expect to rollback often. Its just to make it easier for Ops in the event of a rollback - rather than going through the motions of reverting, creating the rollback branch etc.